# how to arrange set of number to form pair of 10%,30%,30%,30%

Tags: python, algorithm

The requirement for me is to distribute 4000 tests across 4 sets each of 10,30,30,30. These tests will have the dependency and will form a sequence such as 
s1-s50 and all 4000 tests are distributed in sequence set.
Now each set to be distributed in 10%, 30%, 30 % ,30 % to make an optimal set.
Example (14,17,25,11,14,14,5)  which all sum up 100 will be paired as 11,(14,14,5),(14,17), 25 to form the near by combination of 11,33,31,25 .(matching to expected 10,30,30,30)

what will be the algorithm to fulfill the above requiremt

Comment: This looks like a case of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), though that's usually presented as splitting the set in half.

Comment: Thanks  Patrick Haugh, provided me good idea. but for me, the split should work  for odd/even an to work with 10%, 30 % like that , not just equal half